# inconsistent flex-grow-1 behavior in Visual Studio or (maybe) Razor?

Tags: bootstrap-4, visual-studio-2019, blazor, blazor-server-side

I tested the following styling in codeply and it works as documented by Bootstrap, but when I move this code to a Razor component (Blazor).  The flex-grow-1 does not work at all.

I opened the bootstrap.min.css and it says it's 4.3.1, so technically I have everything I needed.  Did the Blazor server overwrites the Bootstrap layout?

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0 d-flex flex-column h-100">
   <div class="navbar">
     <label class="navbar-brand">MAP</label>
   </div>
<div class="content flex-grow-1" style="background-color:yellow">
  hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the h-100 to min-vh-100 and it works...despite that codeply frowns on the change.